# How does one check what websites a person logs into using their Google account?

Tags: google-account, security

When you create Stack Exchange accounts and you want them tied to a Google account, when you log into your Google account you get taken to a separate page where it asks for permission and whether you want the setting to be remembered.

I am wondering how I can access the page which lists what accounts are tied to my Google account and have set to remember.

I think it's about time I went in and see what accounts I am not using and get rid of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to:

> https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Alternatively, go to https://myaccount.google.com > *Apps with account access > Manage Apps*

You will be prompted for your password. After that, you're shown a list of all sites you've used Google to authenticate with, and applications that have access to your account.